# Crystal Reports Asking For Database Login Information?

Tags: .net, security, ms-access, authentication, crystal-reports

I am using an Access database with no particular security setup. I can open the database just fine through Explorer but when I try to open a report it asks for the login credentials of which there aren't any. I noticed in the Database Login dialog that there's a field that says "Server Name" and it's the Namespace and Class name to the object I'm using in my report. What is causing this?

```
///DAL Class
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports FPCReportBuilder.Utilities
Namespace FPCReportBuilder.Data
    Public Class DAL
        Inherits DALCnn
        Public Shared Function GetDataTableUsingReader(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal parameterList As List(Of DataParameter) = Nothing, Optional ByVal type As CmdType = CmdType.StoredProcedure) As DataTable
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = CreateCommand(sql, parameterList, type)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Using cmd.Connection
                cmd.Connection.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            End Using
            Return dt
        End Function

        Private Shared Function CreateCommand(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal parameters As List(Of DataParameter) = Nothing, Optional ByVal type As CmdType = CmdType.StoredProcedure) As OleDbCommand
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, GetConnection())
            If type = CmdType.StoredProcedure Then
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Else
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            End If
            If Not parameters Is Nothing Then
                For Each parameter As DataParameter In parameters
                    Dim newParameter As OleDbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
                    newParameter.ParameterName = parameter.Name
                    newParameter.Value = parameter.Value
                    newParameter.OleDbType = parameter.DbType
                    newParameter.Direction = parameter.Direction
                    newParameter.Size = parameter.Size
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(newParameter)
                Next
            End If
            Return cmd
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace

///DALCnn Class
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Namespace FPCReportBuilder.Data
    Public MustInherit Class DALCnn
        Protected Friend Shared Function GetConnection() As OleDbConnection
            Return New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.cnnString)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This all works fine when I run it through code. When I call a class like, ReportData.GetSection1Complete() which is a Public Shared Method, it brings the data back just fine.

Edit*

I seem to be getting somewhere. I have added a ReportDate property to the Page Footer of the MainReport.rpt file to show on each page of the report. When I fire the btnViewReport.Click method, the ReportViewer form that contains the actual Crystal ReportViewer control, I fill the datasource like so...

```
Private Sub btnViewReport_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnViewReport.Click
        Try
            Dim repViewer As New ReportViewer()
            Dim reportList As New List(Of Report)
            reportList.Add(objReport)
            repViewer.MainReport1.Database.Tables("Report").SetDataSource(reportList)
Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

This seems to work. But the MainReport.rpt contains a SubReport, which contains a SubReport as well. I'm trying to call a Method from another Class called ReportData.GetSection1Complete() to fill the data in the SubReport but I can't seem to figure out how to fill that particular DataSource. I tried...

```
repViewer.MainReport1.Subreports("Section1.rpt").Subreports("Section1Complete.rpt").Database.Tables("ReportData").SetDataSource(ReportData.GetSection1Complete())
```

That gives me an "Not supported within subreports." exception.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using for authentication.

Comment: Adding the class code is a good start. Now, what does `My.Settings.cnnString` look like? Please don't "fudge" it. If you want to obfuscate a password that fine, but otherwise show us *exactly* what it looks like.

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\FPC_Reporting.accdb

There is no password... That's the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly why I was asked to logon but I found out that if I don't populate the object datasources beforehand that it does this. When I populated the datasources on the button click that loaded up the report viewer, it doesn't ask for a logon. Another issue I had was that when I had a subreport within a subreport, it would not show. After some more research I found that you can't have subreports within subreports so when I decapsulated the reports the data now shows just fine. Thanks for the help from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Access to open a database that does not have User-Level Security configured then you are automatically (and silently) logged in as the user `Admin`. When Crystal Reports prompts you for credentials try using the Username `Admin` with an empty password. If that works, then see if Crystal Reports offers the option to "save password" or "save login information" or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this suggestion still gives me a failed logon.

Comment: Also, my data source is a class object so I don't understand why Crystal Reports would even ask for a password to the database.

Comment: @user1066133 If your class object contains a connection string then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16243953/edit) your question to include that.

Comment: The class does not. The class connects to another class, which connects to another class that holds the connection information.